# MVC Check if returned user from database is active user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I have problem authenticating selected user from the database based on the returned items. I have found a solution, however I don't really think that it's correct (even though it is working).

Here is what is going on (simplified).
I have the following class connected to database:

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }               
    public ApplicationUser CEO { get; set; }
}
```

Which means that one company can have a single CEO (owner of a company), but CEO can have multiple companies (different story, just explaining for now).

Then I have a **Controller** `CompaniesController` which looks like this:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var items = _context.Companies.Include(n=>n.CEO).ToList();
    return View(items);
}
```

Which returns `List<Company>` of all companies that are in the database. Furthermore, if I do not enter `.Include(n=>n.CEO)`, then CEO field will be null.

Finally on a **View** I have the following thing:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.CompanyName</td>
        <td>@item.Description</td>

        @if (@item.CEO?.Email == User.Identity.Name)
        {
            //Show edit button for CEO
            <td><a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a></td>
        }
        else
        {
            //Logged user is not expected user therefore insert empty column and do not show button
            <td></td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```

The way how I am checking whether returned `CEO` from my model is actively logged in user is by comparing their email addresses (User need to be authorized to enter this page therefore he will always be logged in).

**The question**: Is there a better, more elegant way how to check whether the active user is CEO for each item in `List<Company>` or is this a correct approach?

Furthermore, is the way how I store user data to the `Company` database table correct? I have adopted native Identity model which automatically generates 4 or 5 identity tables in the database and therefore when I check my CEO field in SQL database, I can see that is just a reference to `UserId`.

Any help / suggestions in this matter would be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1: You can write a helper method which will return on

```
def method(signed_in_user, company_id)
  # it will return if the user is CEO of that company id or Not
end
```

2: You can make the filter showing all the companies and owned companies Like bootstrap data toggle.

3: You can make two database calls 
    1: user.companies(where he is ceo)
    2: companies.where(signed_in user is not ceo)
 Write your for loops.

I am not into C# programming but this patterns may help